# Consulta Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, join

Boa tarde

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabelas:

-Usuario

-Grupo

-Permissao

E todas as relações N pra N:

- GrupoUsuario
- PermissaoUsuario
- PermissaoGrupo

Montei uma consulta pra retornar o usuário, independente de Grupos e Permissões (LEFT JOIN) com Linq em C#.

Segue:

```
tbUsuario = (from _u in _authEntities.tb_usuario
                          join _gu in _authEntities.tb_grupo_usuario on _u.id_tb_usuario equals _gu.id_tb_usuario
                          into u
                          from usuario in u.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join _pu in _authEntities.tb_permissao_usuario on _u.id_tb_usuario equals _pu.id_tb_usuario
                          into p
                          from permissao in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where _u.login == login && _u.senha == senha
                          select _u).SingleOrDefault();
```

O que preciso é incluir nesta consulta que já possuo, mais um LEFT JOIN, para a tabela de PermissaoGrupo.

Se fosse por query SQL seria simples, porém com LINQ ainda não encontrei a solução. Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Faça os LEFT JOIN para as tabelas tb_Grupo e tb_Permissao e depois outro LEFT JOIN para a tabela tb_PermissaoGrupo com as duas chaves dos dois ultimo JOIN...

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer os relacionamentos da seguinte forma.

```
tbUsuario = (from _u in _authEntities.tb_usuario
                          join _gu in _authEntities.tb_grupo_usuario on _u.id_tb_usuario equals _gu.id_tb_usuario
                          into u
                          from usuario in u.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join _pu in _authEntities.tb_permissao_usuario on _u.id_tb_usuario equals _pu.id_tb_usuario
                          into p
                          from permissao in p.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join g in _authEntities.tb_grupo on u.id_tb_grupo equals g.id_tb_grupo
                          into g
                          from Grupo in g.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join per in _authEntities.tb_permissao on per.id_tb_permissao equals p.id_tb_permissao
                          into per
                          from permi in per.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join pergru in _authEntities.tb_Permissao_Grupo on new { Grupo.id_tb_grupo, permi.id_tb_permissao } equals new { pergru.id_tb_grupo, pergru.id_tb_permissao }
                          into pergru
                          from Permissao_Grupo in pergru.DefaultIfEmpty()


                          where _u.login == login && _u.senha == senha
                          select _u).SingleOrDefault();
```

Não fiz os teste para ver se a sintaxe esta correta, tenha isso como exemplo de como fazer.

Comment: Marconcilio Ainda não está certo.
Na verdade porque no trecho onde você sugeriu o join com a tabela 'tb_grupo',
a entidade '_u' da 'tb_usuario' possui uma lista de grupos (tb_grupo_usuario). Sendo assim, não consigo acessar o ID do grupo. O mesmo para as permissões. Se tiver alguma outra dica pra me ajudar a resolver, fico agradecido.